# What's a proper term for a 'bill presenter'?

Tags: word-request

I saw this -

[image]

I'm not convinced with the **phrase** 'bill presenter' (a person specially appointed to present a bill is also a 'bill presenter!'- just a tongue-in-cheek comment!) and looking for the better/proper **term**.

It's bigger than a normal wallet in my pocket but smaller than a menu.

Comment: "check presenter" ~50 million results

Comment: @Phil Unfortunately, the whopping number of Google results don't fascinate me ;P

Comment: "a person specially appointed to present a bill is also a 'bill presenter!'" -yes, and a person especially appointed to write up type (imprinted text!) is also a 'typewriter'. The fact there never was (afaik) any confusion between a machine (typewriter) or a person (copywriter), seems to indicate that speakers of English adapt quite well to these kind of word formations :)

Comment: @oerkelens nope, it'd be then a 'typer' or 'writer'. And also, 'typewriter' is a single word ;) but good one! haha

Comment: @MaulikV I understand that. I was trying to show that there are other terms that also provide plenty of results. I'm happy to see that the revised answer has used more terms.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's first important to note for our ESL/EFL friends that one would practically never have a need to refer to one of these. (I personally don't ever recall hearing any name for this.) If one wants to ask for a bill in a restaurant, the answer is here: [how should I ask for a bill in a restaurant politely](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/904/how-should-i-ask-for-a-bill-in-a-restaurant-politely).

This is the leather (or faux leather) folder that waiters/waitresses use to deliver the check/bill to the customer, who reviews the bill and encloses cash or a credit card back to the waiter. The following are terms used by several online restaurant supply distributors:<sup>1</sup>

- Guest Check Presenter, Guest Check Holder
- Check Presenter, Check Holder
- Bill Presenter, Bill Holder
- Check Presentation Cover
- Bill Presentation Folder

Most people have never considered what this is called, but would likely use the following:

- (bill | check) + (holder | folder) <sup>2</sup>
- So for example, if it was misplaced and separated from the bill, one might ask, **"Where's the (black) bill holder?"**.
- If it was misplaced with the bill, one may simply ask **"Where's the bill?"**
- Another functional way people talk about something when their mind isn't focused is to describe it in terms of how it is used: **"that black thing/thingy that the waiter brings with the bill in it."**

Here are a few Google Results:

- Google Search [`"bill presenter"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bill+presenter%22) 189K results
- Google Search [`"guest+check+presenter"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="guest+check+presenter") 86K results
- Google Search [`"check presenter"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22check+presenter%22) 31K results

This is similar to they way I sometimes describe the TV **remote control** to my wife late at night: "Darling, do you know where the **channel changer** is?"  (Evidently I'm not alone on this with Google [`"channel+changer" "remote+control"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22channel+changer%22+%22remote+control%22) at 14K results.)

---

<sup>1. www.bigtray.com, www.usaequipmentdirect.com, www.centralrestaurant.com, www.zesco.com, www.foodservicewarehouse.com</sup>

<sup>2. AmE uses *check* or *bill*.  BrE uses *bill*.</sup>

Comment: *billfold* is *wallet* and not a *bill presenter.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/billfold I said it's bigger than wallet and smaller than menu.

Comment: I've fixed the answer again, adding more detail.

Comment: yup, it's better now ;) +1

Comment: Thanks, please note I made another change (added an intro paragraph) after you upvoted.